# Chord Practice Right Hand

Tags: piano, chords

I am seeking a chart or music notation of all
common chords with the melody note on top.

Say the melody note is C. What are all the chords with C on top.  An example would be Cm- EbGC
C-EGC  Am EAC,  F FAC.  Then repeat for all 12
keys incline common chords I have left out.

When playing from a lead sheet you play the melody note with the pinky.  Then you must immediately play the correct inversion etc.

A good drill would include all chords the the same note on top. By playing the drill it would reinforce learning the correct inversions, chords.

Comment: @your_uncle_bob same question by the same user but it was closed as unclear.

Comment: Are we talking just major or minor chords? Just diatonic chords in a certain key? Just triads? Because once you add all the qualities of 7th chords (dom, min7, maj7, aug, etc) and also sus4, add9, 11ths, etc, you’re talking about a mighty big chart with probably thousands of chords.

Comment: A good exercise may be to take a song where you have a lead sheet with the chords and the melody laid out for you and then try to play both the chord and the melody with just the right hand. Maybe play the bass in the left.

Comment: @b3ko Yes, I know, that's why I flagged this as a duplicate. If a question is closed as unclear, the asker should try to clarify it instead of posting it again. If you have a comment, you should post it under the original question, and if you have an answer, you should vote to get the question re-opened.

Comment: I agree with b3ko. This is a good idea. Another method would be to notate this liste by yourself. Thinking, playing, touching, listening, writing, reflecting: = theory and practice!

Comment: It wouldn't reinforce things in a particularly helpful manner. Since the vast majority of songs are diatonic, you'd be using chords in the key. So, in key C, with a C  in the melody, the choice for triads is only C, F or Am. Once you go beyond triads, the number of potential chords - especially non-diatonics - is exponentially grown. By the time you consulted the 'list', the song would be over!

Comment: I just don't get it. OP wants to learn to play chord inversions, and some people think this is off-topic, and closing this question makes the world better somehow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just asks for a resource, or for someone else to do the work of writing out a list of chords.

Comment: This isn't how a lead sheet is read. The melody note is often a _non chord tone_. Actually, that's the case for most songs, regardless of using a lead sheet. As far as learning inversion is concerned, playing common harmony patterns through 3 or 4 inversions is the simple, direct way to do it: just play them all. Keep in mind the difference between chord "position" in the right hand versus proper _inversion_ which always is a matter of what the lowest bass tone is (most likely played in left hand not right)

Comment: The list of chords is of course a non-working solution. I gave him an answer, with an exercise, how to practice chord inversions for getting better at what he's trying to do, i.e. playing both the melody and chords with the right hand. "Chord Practice Right Hand" is the title. The whole "inversion" business is over-appreciated to begin with. Play the melody note and add chord tones below it - how is it even possible that this is difficult to do for a keyboard player. For guitarists I can understand that it's more difficult and inversions have to be actually practiced.

Answer (score 0):

For playing melody and chords with the right hand, instead of "memorizing" all inversions, I think it's better to just combine the melody note and add chord notes below it, until the needed notes are covered and/or you run out of fingers. It is a quite mechanical thing to do, but a big list of chord diagrams isn't going to help. You should rather be able to reconstruct inversions on the fly.

You see, the piano keyboard is full of C major. **"Inversions" are only narrow windows into the infinite array of chord notes**, like this:
[image: C major inversions on piano keyboard]

When playing melody and chords with your right hand, you slide the window (red rectangle) in the above picture so that its right-hand side is at or as close to the melody note as possible.

If you want exercises, here are some:

- Take a chord, for example C major, and play all of its inversions from lowest to highest, like what the animation above shows. Then do the same in reverse order.
- Take a song and its chord progression, keep the right-hand's pinky finger at or close to some fixed key like C, and play the chord progressions with the rest of the right-hand fingers.
- Take a song and its chord progression, and accompany the song using different inversions in sequence like this:

Even though the inversions just go up and down quite mechanically, it starts to resemble a melody, don't you think?